# Definite integral with interval depends on $n$!

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The following that 
$$\int_0^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(\frac{k}{n})\frac{1}{n} \, $$ 
is well-known fact! But if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{r_n}{n}=\alpha,$$ 
then is it true that $$\int_0^{\alpha} f(x) \,\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{r_n-1}f(\frac{k}{n})\frac{1}{n} \, $$?

If this is true, why? Help me with big mercy!!

Comment: Substitute $y=x/\alpha$, then define $g(y):=f(y\alpha)$.